# Как при клике сменить спрайт в объекте?

Tags: unity3d, 2d, спрайт

Получилось поменять цвет объекта на синий при клике.
Но не понял как менять спрайт.

Кажется в руководстве это описывается [здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-sprite.html)

А я не силен в английском

```
// Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);

            if (hit)
            {
                //hit.collider.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.blue;
                hit.collider.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = //? что сюда написать
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> hit.collider.GetComponent().sprite = //? что сюда написать

Собственно с правой стороны надо дать объект типа [Sprite](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.html).

А каким способом он там окажется уже без разницы. Например самый стандартный способ это указать публичное поле с таким типом

```
public Sprite mySprite;
```

потом в редакторе в это поле положить спрайт, а уже в той строке выше присвоить полю....поле))

```
hit.collider.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = mySprite
```

А в примере по ссылке указывается, как можно загрузить спрайт из ресурсов и далее этот самый спрайт (точнее один спрайт из массива) вставляется в `GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite`.

Comment: Не подскажите как загрузить спрайт из ресурсов? Подгрузить и выбрать нужный в mySprite

Comment: @ЖалгасАжибаев создаете папку `Resources` туда кидаете спрайт, названный например `testSprite`....Далее пользуетесь методом [Resources.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) .Он загружает из ресурсов..Напр. будет `var loadedSprite =  Resources.Load("testSprite") as Sprite;` ...Т.к. ресурс не знает какого типа объект он загружает, то надо специально привести к нужному типу, для этого написано `as Sprite` ....И вставляете его уже куда надо `hit.collider.GetComponent().sprite = loadedSprite;` советую изучать англ. в доках всё написано подробно